# How can I convert data url to valid url so that it can be posted on Facebook Page by Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to send a data URL as an URL parameter of Facebook-graph-API to post a photo on Facebook Page. It is working perfectly for normal URL image, but not working for data url.

This is the function where I am getting my data URL for selected image file from a `<input type=file">`

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      function() {
        var avatarImg = new Image();
        var src = reader.result;
        avatarImg.src = src;
        document.getElementById("imageToUrlHolderID").value = src;
      },
      false
    );
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

And this is the call for facebook page image post

```
function uploadButtonAction() {
  //var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=112fWlDGfGiYAGlr9i0Sl5-bl7QSzytNp";
  var url = document.getElementById("imageToUrlHolderID").value;
  console.log(document.getElementById("imageToUrlHolderID").value);

  FB.api(
    '/'+pageID+'/photos',
    'POST',
    {"url":url, "access_token":document.getElementById("pageAccessToken").value},
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
      } else {
        getAllUploadedImageURL(response);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

When ever I try it with data url it keeps saying `message: "(#100) url should represent a valid URL"`, so my question is how can I convert my data url to valid url.
Thanks!

Comment: Facebook only allows HTTP or HTTPS for uploads via URL. You can upload binary image data via the `source` parameter, but you’ll have to figure out how to make that multipart/form-data request then, I don’t know if that is possible directly using FB.api. You might need to make your own AJAX or fetch based request instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the suggestion. I would research on this. :)